# LESS selectors: how to apply styling only for one of the elements from inside mixin?

Tags: css, less, mixins

I have a code that I can't change:

```
item.left,
item.centre,
item.right{
.MIXIN();
}

.MIXIN(){
width: 100px;
}
```

I need to apply width only to .right element. I can only change contents of `MIXIN()`. I was thinking of using `&`but it will result either in `.right item.right` or `item.right .right` which is not what I want. Is there a way to apply styling only for `.right` element using contents of `MIXIN()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the negation CSS pseudo-class [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

```
item.left,
item.centre,
item.right{
  width: 20px; 

  &:not(.left):not(.centre) {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e0nd7pk4

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it. The only way is to override the first declaration.

```
   item.left,
   item.centre {
       width: inherit;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about & but without the space:

```
.MIXIN() {
    width: 100px;
    &.right { color: red; }
}
```

It compiles down to `item.right.right` which is a bit weird but won't match left and center.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c0634wg2/